# Hibernate property references a null

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a problem with Hibernate: I have two entities Libro and Editorial with a Many-to-One relationship. When I try to persist appears this error:

> Hibernate: select editorial_.ID_EDITORIAL, editorial_.NOMBRE as NOMBRE4_, editorial_.ID_DIRECCION as ID3_4_, editorial_.NIF as NIF4_ from EDITORIAL editorial_ where editorial_.ID_EDITORIAL=?
>   org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: app.modelo.Libro.editorial
>       at org.hibernate.engine.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:313)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:144)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
>       at app.persistencia.LibrosDAO.altaLibro(LibrosDAO.java:41)
>       at app.negocio.GestionLibreria.altaLibro(GestionLibreria.java:26)
>       at app.cliente.Main.main(Main.java:98)
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:312)
>       at app.persistencia.LibrosDAO.altaLibro(LibrosDAO.java:49)
>       at app.negocio.GestionLibreria.altaLibro(GestionLibreria.java:26)
>       at app.cliente.Main.main(Main.java:99)

As I read in other questions I think is a problem with the Editorial Foreign Key but I really can't find and solve the error.
Here the code :

EDITORIAL MAPPING

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<class name="app.modelo.Editorial" table="EDITORIAL">

    <!-- Clave Primaria -->

    <id name="ID_editorial" column="ID_EDITORIAL" type="int" >
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>


    <!-- Propriedades -->

    <property name="nombre" column="NOMBRE" type="string" lazy="false" not-null="false"/>

    <many-to-one unique="true" name="direccion" column="ID_DIRECCION" not-null="true" cascade="all"/> <!--  Simulamos un Many to One con la entidad Editorial para generar una Foreing Key -->

    <property name="nif" column="NIF" type="string" lazy="false" not-null="false"/>

    <set name="libros" cascade="all" >
        <key column="ID_EDITORIAL" />
        <one-to-many class="app.modelo.Editorial" />
    </set>


</class>
```

LIBRO MAPPING

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="app.modelo.Libro" table="LIBROS">

    <!-- Clave Primaria -->

    <id name="ID" column="ID_LIBRO" type="int" >
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>       

    <!-- Propriedades -->

    <property name="titulo" type="string" column="TITULO" lazy="false"/>

    <property name="isbn" type="string" column="ISBN" lazy="false"/>

    <property name="publicacion" type="int" column="PUBLICACION" lazy="false"/>

    <property name="precio" type="double" column="PRECIO" lazy="false"/>

    <property name="descripcion" type="string" column="DESCRIPCION" lazy="true" />

    <many-to-one name="editorial" column="ID_EDITORIAL" class="app.modelo.Editorial" not-null="true" />

    <set name="autores" inverse="true" table="AUTOR_LIBRO" cascade="all">   <!-- Gestionamos el Many to Many con AUTOR haciendo referencia a la tabla intermedia  -->
        <key column="ID_LIBRO" />   <!-- Nueva columna en la tabla intermedia  -->
        <many-to-many column="ID_AUTOR" class="app.modelo.Autor" />
    </set>

</class>
```

CLASS LIBROSDAO

```
public class LibrosDAO implements ItfzLibrosDao {

SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate2.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Session session = sf.openSession();

Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();

/*
 * Crea un nuevo registro en la tabla con los datos del libro recibido como
 * argumento
 */

public boolean altaLibro(Libro libro) {
    // Creo una variable de tipo boolean que me retorna si se ha podido o no
    // insertar un nuevo libro
    boolean insertado = false;

    Libro l = new Libro(libro.getID(),libro.getTitulo(),libro.getAutores(),libro.getEditorial(),libro.getIsbn(),
            libro.getPublicacion(),libro.getPrecio(),libro.getDescripcion());

    try {
        tx.begin();

        session.save(l);
        tx.commit();
        insertado= true;    
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            insertado = false;
        } finally {
            session.close();

        }

        return insertado;
}
```

GESTIONLIBRERIA CLASS

```
public class GestionLibreria implements ItfzGestionLibreria {

LibrosDAO dao = new LibrosDAO();

public boolean altaLibro(Libro libro) {

    int ID = libro.getID();
    String titulo = libro.getTitulo();
    Set<Autor> autores = libro.getAutores();
    Editorial editorial = libro.getEditorial();
    String isbn = libro.getIsbn();
    int publicacion = libro.getPublicacion();
    double precio = libro.getPrecio();
    String descripcion = libro.getDescripcion();
    dao.altaLibro(new Libro(ID, titulo, autores, editorial, isbn, publicacion, precio, descripcion));

    return false;
}
```

MAIN:

```
case 1:


        // Crear Editoriales

        Editorial e1 = new Editorial(1,"Editorial UNO", d1, "A111111");
        Editorial e2 = new Editorial(2,"Editorial DOS", d2, "B222222");
        Editorial e3 = new Editorial(3,"Editorial TRES", d3, "C333333");



        // Crear Libros

        Libro l1 = new Libro(1, "Libro 1", e1, "1111A", 2001, 11.11, "Este es el libro numero 1");
        Libro l2 = new Libro(2, "Libro 2", e1, "2222B", 2002, 22.22, "Este es el libro numero 2");
        Libro l3 = new Libro(3, "Libro 3", e1, "3333C", 2003, 33.33, "Este es el libro numero 3");
        Libro l4 = new Libro(4, "Libro 4", e2, "4444D", 2004, 44.44, "Este es el libro numero 4");
        Libro l5 = new Libro(5, "Libro 5", e2, "5555D", 2005, 55.55, "Este es el libro numero 5");
        Libro l6 = new Libro(6, "Libro 6", e3, "6666E", 2006, 66.66, "Este es el libro numero
```

CLASS LIBRO:

```
public class Libro implements Serializable {


/* 
 *          Declaracion de variables 
 */


private int ID, publicacion;
private String titulo, isbn, descripcion;
private Editorial editorial;
private Set<Autor> autores = new HashSet<Autor>();
private double precio;


/*
 *          Contructores
 *
 */

public Libro( int ID, String titulo, Set<Autor> autores, Editorial editorial, String isbn,
        int publicacion, double precio, String descripcion ) {

    this.ID = ID;   
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autores = autores;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.publicacion = publicacion;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;

}

public Libro(int ID, String titulo, Editorial editorial, String isbn, int publicacion, double precio, String descripcion ) {

    this.ID = ID;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.publicacion = publicacion;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;

}

public Libro()
{

}


/*
 *          Get&Set
 * 
 */



public int getID() {
    return ID;
}


public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}


public int getPublicacion() {
    return publicacion;
}


public void setPublicacion(int publicacion) {
    this.publicacion = publicacion;
}


public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}


public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}


public Set<Autor> getAutores() {
    return autores;
}


public void setAutores(Set<Autor> autores) {
    this.autores = autores;
}   


public Editorial getEditorial() {
    return editorial;
}


public void setEditorial(Editorial editorial) {
    this.editorial = editorial;
}


public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}


public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}


public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}


public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}


public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}


public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}


/*
 * Metodo toString()
 */

public String toString() {
    return "Libro [ID = " + ID + ", Publicacion = " + publicacion + ", Titulo = " + titulo + ", Autores = " + autores
            + ", Editorial = " + editorial + ", Isbn = " + isbn + ", Descripcion = " + descripcion + ", Precio = " + precio
            + "]";
}

/*
 * hashCode()
 */


public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ID;
    return result;
}


/*
 * equals()
 */


public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Libro other = (Libro) obj;
    if (ID != other.ID)
        return false;
    return true;
}


/*
 * Metodos de sincronizaccion
 * 
 */

public void addAutor(Autor a){
    autores.add(a);
}
```

}

CLASS EDITORIAL:

```
public class Editorial {

private int ID_editorial;
private String nombre;
private Direccion direccion;
private String nif;
private Set<Libro> libros;


/*
 *  Constructores
 */

public Editorial(int ID_editorial, String nombre, Direccion direccion, String nif, Set<Libro> libros) {

    this.ID_editorial = ID_editorial;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.nif = nif;
    this.libros = libros;

}

public Editorial(int ID_editorial, String nombre, Direccion direccion, String nif) {

    this.ID_editorial = ID_editorial;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.nif = nif;

}

public Editorial(){

}


/*
 *  Get & Set
 */

public int getID_editorial() {
    return ID_editorial;
}

public void setID_editorial(int ID_editorial)
{
    this.ID_editorial = ID_editorial;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getNif() {
    return nif;
}

public void setNif(String nif) {
    this.nif = nif;
}

public Set<Libro> getLibros() {
    return libros;
}

public void setLibros(Set<Libro> libros) {
    this.libros = libros;
}


/*
 *  Metodo toString()
 */



public String toString() {
    return "Editorial [Id Editorial=" + ID_editorial + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", nif=" + nif + ", libros=" + libros + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your session handling is wrong, change your Class LibrosDAO into:

```
public class LibrosDAO implements ItfzLibrosDao {

SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate2.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Session session;

Transaction tx;

/*
 * Crea un nuevo registro en la tabla con los datos del libro recibido como
 * argumento
 */

public boolean altaLibro(Libro libro) {
    // Creo una variable de tipo boolean que me retorna si se ha podido o no
    // insertar un nuevo libro
    session = sf.openSession();
    boolean insertado = false;

    Libro l = new Libro(libro.getID(),libro.getTitulo(),libro.getAutores(),libro.getEditorial(),libro.getIsbn(),
            libro.getPublicacion(),libro.getPrecio(),libro.getDescripcion());

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(l);
        tx.commit();
        insertado= true;    
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            insertado = false;
        } finally {
            session.close();

        }

        return insertado;
}
```